# IE7 Partialview with fieldset is causing underlines

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9, fieldset, underline, asp.net-mvc-partialview

Hello people from stackoverflow
I have found more IE7 problems (tested in compatibility mode of IE9). I am trying to dynamically load a partialView into my page through the use of JQuery, like this:

```
$('#PartialContainer').load('@Url.Action("LoadPartial", "Controller", new { Id = Model.Id })');
```

Now the problem i am getting is that the Partial has a fieldset tag inside the page, an under the legend sit a few lines of text. The problem is that the text is underlined with the lines of the fieldset (the borders), But for some reason the underlines to not appear underneath the legend. the partial look like this:

```
<fieldset>
<legend>Partial</legend>

<div class="explanation">
    The underlined text is here!
</div>
</fieldset>
```

Has anybody else encountered this problem before, and what was your solution?

PS: this does NOT happen in crome, firefox or IE9.

PS2: it is in a ASP.NET 4.0 MVC 3.0 project.

EDIT:

Here is a picture of the problem: http://i1073.photobucket.com/albums/w382/kroeze1992/IE7UnderlinedBug.png

Comment: Any chance of a screenshot of the issue? Not really sure exactly what the problem is. Also im assuming that there is a closing fieldset tag?

Comment: @HenryGarle I added a picture as you requested. hope this will help.

Comment: Does it help if you attatch padding/margins to the div inside of the fieldset? Or adding padding/margins to the fieldset/legend its self? Ive seen this problem before a very long time ago. Would it be possible for you to add styles you are applying to them to your post so I can see if I can reproduce it? Sorry for asking for the extra info but it will help to try to get to the issue. (Or a link to a live example)

Comment: Im using http://jsbin.com/abidom/2/edit#javascript,html,live as my example, feel free to edit it with your css and then let me know the updated link if that is easier.

Comment: I have been experimenting with developer tools, and it seems that the problem is caused by font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Lucida Grande", "Segoe UI", Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif and font-size: medium. if i remove the font-size it fixes the lines completely, but with font-family it fixes for every line but the first.

Comment: It also happens with non-partial views.

Comment: Found what was causing the problem: font-style: italic, thank you for the help :)

Comment: Glad you got it fixed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was caused by font-style: italic. i removed the font-style and no more underlines :).